# How do I dereference this member?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
struct myStruct
{
    myClass* member;
}

myStruct *s = (myStruct*) someVariable;
```

I now want the value from `s->member` to go into `myFunction (myClass c)`. How do I dereference it?

Comment: what is `someVariable` and why are you casting it?

Comment: s->member should dereference it? what is the question?

Comment: a `void *` and because I have to, its part of the function call that I can't change. I believe what the block below posted works.

Comment: What's wrong with myFunction(s->member) ?

Comment: @ScottHunter : was giving me a compile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
*(s->member) <------ Gives you a `myClass` object
```

Same as you do for pointers with structures.

```
void myFunction (myClass c)
{


}
```

call it as:

```
int main()
{
    myFunction(*(s->member));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dereference pointers using `operator*`.  In this case, you would do `*s->member`.  There is no need for parentheses around `s->member`.

As things are, it is unclear why you're casting `someVariable` to a `myStruct*`.

You are also missing a `;` after the struct definition.

Comment: There is no need for parentheses around `s->member`. but it gives good readability so there is no need to advocate omitting the `()`.

Comment: Care to explain why there is 'no need for parentheses around s->member'?

Comment: @Als: Personally, I find omitting the parentheses easier to read.  Seeing as redundant parentheses may be added at will, I find it of more use to show the form that lacks them.

Comment: @TomKnapen: It's just the way C++ syntax works -- `*p->m` is equivalent to `*(p->m)`, not `(*p)->m`.  It makes sense, as the latter would make `operator->` much less useful.

Comment: @Anton agreed even though we're going into stylistic territory of not much significance, I never did care for superfluous parentheses and decorations in code. I find them harder to read than the more concise version without them. Ex: return (x + y) to me implies at first glance that the parentheses would be necessary where as just return x + y is more succinct and implies to me a better understanding of expressions. Oh well, style debates never go anywhere. :-D